# What's my Synlogy address for webdav?

Tags: networking, server

I am new to Ubuntu and I am trying to connect to my Synology NAS, which is a DS213j, to see shared folders which I can see nicely from my Windows 10 PC.

I followed the [instructions on the Synology site here](https://www.synology.com/en-uk/knowledgebase/DSM/tutorial/File_Sharing/How_to_access_files_on_Synology_NAS_with_WebDAV#t1_1)  but when it comes to "enter the server address" I do not know what to put.  Neither `http:` not `dav:` are acceptable server types.

What address should I use please?

All I want is a nice, easy-to-use graphical interface!

Comment: The instructions for Ubuntu are quite clear: dav://IP_address:port. Please double-check and try again. Edit and post the exact error message if it doesn't work.

Comment: Thank you.  I did exactly the same thing again (as far as I can tell) and this time it worked perfectly.

Answer (score 0):

The instructions [here](https://www.synology.com/en-uk/knowledgebase/DSM/tutorial/File_Sharing/How_to_access_files_on_Synology_NAS_with_WebDAV#t2_3) say it must be configured with:

```
dav://IP_address:port
```